# Matching pattern present in one column should replace with the entry of second file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace

I have two files
file1.txt

```
ID  AB  AC  AD  AE
L   5   6   7   5
M   4   5   6   4
O   2   4   6   8
P   7   9   6   5
Q   7   8   6   5
```

file2.txt

```
AB  BB
AC  HG
AD  ZH
AE  BE
```

result_file.txt

```
ID  BB  HG  ZH  BE
L   5   6   7   5
M   4   5   6   4
O   2   4   6   8
P   7   9   6   5
Q   7   8   6   5
```

How I can get this output. I know that sed can be used for substitution, but how I can apply it on multiple entries.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: to get you started try a google search on `bash replace multiple patterns` and then review the (lengthy) list of hits for ideas that fit your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/(\S+)\s+(\S+).*/1s#\1#\2#/' file2 | sed -f - file1
```

Used file2 to create a sed script for transforming the header of file1.

Comment: Can you please explain the whole command?

Comment: @Mendel the first sed invocation takes each line of file2 and turns it into a sed command e.g. first line of file2 is `AB BB` becomes `1s#AB#BB#` this is passed as sed script to the second sed invocation which changes the first line from `ID  AB  AC  AD  AE` to `ID  BB  AC  AD  AE` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { arr[$1]=$2 } NR != FNR && FNR == 1 { printf "%s  ","ID";for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { printf "%s  ",arr[$i] } } NR != FNR && FNR != 1 { printf "\n%s",$0 }' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Process file2.txt (NR==FNR) and create an array (arr) indexed with the first column and the value from the second column. Then process the second file (NR != FNR) For the first line, loop through the space separated fields starting from 2 and print the value corresponding to the index in array arr. Then print the lines as is.